# What is an opposite joke?

Tags: terminology

In one of *Monk* episodes, the lead character speaks derogatorily about a radio host who has written a book consisting of cheap stylistic and narrative tricks, gimmicks, etc, etc, and "opposite jokes."

What is an opposite joke?

Comment: I don't know the target audience for *Monk*, but maybe the scriptwriters were just using "opposite joke" as a dumbed-down way of trying to convey the concept of ***sarcasm / irony*** to people who might not understand those terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this word has any definite meaning outside the context of *Monk*, but the show apparently gives an example in the [2007 episode "Mr. Monk is in the Air."](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0940231/quotes)

> Adrian Monk: Did you tell him I was coming?
>
> [Notices a welcome mat that says "GO AWAY" on it]
>
> Natalie Teeger: No, Mr. Monk, that's not for you. That's a joke.
>
> Adrian Monk: How is that a joke?
>
> Natalie Teeger: Well, I guess **it's funny because it says the opposite of what a welcome mat would normally say**.
>
> Adrian Monk: So it's an opposite joke?
>
> Natalie Teeger: Yeah.

So apparently an opposite joke is how Natalie Teeger explains ***irony*** to Monk.

It's possible that in the episode you're referring to, the book that includes "opposite jokes" is a callback to this episode, but that's not something that I personally know.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that was just Monk'being Monk' ;-) and being odd ... as it's not any 'thing' I've have heard of.

However I feel the need to mention it ought to be 
''the lead character made a derogatory comment about''
 rather than  ''speaks derogatorily about''

Hope that helps